# How to drag and drop edit text, radio buttons, view groups(along with child) and layouts in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, radio-button, drag, viewgroup

I have implemented drag and drop on Imageviews, Buttons and Textviews by OnLongClicklistener() and Ondraglistener() but the problem is I am unable to drag and drop edit text, radio buttons, linear/relative layouts and view groups(along with child).

Any method to drag these views in the same way?

Comment: can you explain in more detail what type of error you got.

Comment: It is solved now actually I was not setting tag to the drag able item. Thanks

Comment: Great Happy Coding!!!